# Inner Join MySQL tables with sum of table

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, inner-join

I searched the forum and tried a couple of the results on the form but I am still struggling with the following.
Will you guys please give me advice on the following:

```
Table 1: transactions
Rows: user_id, amount, received

Table 2: wallet
Rows: user_id, wallet_id
```

I have 2 results which I need to join:

Result 1:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(amount)FROM transactions WHERE received = '100' GROUP BY user_id
```

Result 2:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions INNER JOIN wallet ON transactions.user_id = wallet.user_id
```

What I am trying to do is to link the wallet_id of Table 2 by using the user_id and link it to the user_id on all transactions in table 1 which = to 100. I also need to sum the results on the amount row.
So it will display the total of each user_id and link the wallet to it.

I have tried:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(amount)FROM transactions
INNER JOIN wallet ON transactions.user_id = wallet.user_id
WHERE received = '100' GROUP BY user_id
```

but its not working.
Please help guys ;-)

Comment: Please include sample data along with the output you expect from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add group by user_id, wallet_id

```
SELECT user_id, wallet_id, SUM(amount)FROM transactions
INNER JOIN wallet ON transactions.user_id = wallet.user_id
WHERE received = '100' GROUP BY user_id, wallet_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps.

```
SELECT user_id, wallet_id, SUM(amount)FROM transactions t
JOIN wallet w ON t.user_id = w.user_id
WHERE received = '100' GROUP BY user_id, wallet_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you explained why the code is failing, it would be easier to fix.  At least one error is that `user_id` is undefined.

A simple solution is to use `USING`:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(t.amount)
FROM transactions t INNER JOIN
     wallet w
     USING (user_id)
WHERE t.received = '100'
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Note: if `received` is a number, then do not enclose the `100` in single quotes.

Alternative, you can write the query by qualifying the column names -- and you should qualify all of them:

```
SELECT w.user_id, SUM(t.amount)
FROM transactions t INNER JOIN
     wallet w
     ON w.user_id = t.user_id
WHERE t.received = '100'
GROUP BY w.user_id;
```

If you want the `wallet_id` as well, then include it in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT w.user_id, w.wallet_id, SUM(t.amount)
FROM transactions t INNER JOIN
     wallet w
     ON w.user_id = t.user_id
WHERE t.received = '100'
GROUP BY w.user_id, w.wallet_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys. You guys rock!!!!!
This is what worked for me:

SELECT wallet_id, received, SUM(amount)FROM transaction INNER JOIN wallet ON transaction.user_id = wallet.uid WHERE received = '100' GROUP BY wallet_id